# How to obtain registration token from GCM connection servers for Chrome app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-messaging, chrome-gcm

I'm working on a chrome app/extension that receives push notification using Google Cloud Messaging API. And the tutorial that I'm following is [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client). Everything is clear until the "Obtain GCM Registration Token" part.

The code below explains a part of the registration process.

```
function registerCallback(registrationId) {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    // When the registration fails, handle the error and retry the
    // registration later.
    return;
  }

  // Send the registration token to your application server.
  sendRegistrationId(function(succeed) {
    // Once the registration token is received by your server,
    // set the flag such that register will not be invoked
    // next time when the app starts up.
    if (succeed)
      chrome.storage.local.set({registered: true});
  });
}

function sendRegistrationId(callback) {
  // Send the registration token to your application server
  // in a secure way.
}

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
  chrome.storage.local.get("registered", function(result) {
    // If already registered, bail out.
    if (result["registered"])
      return;

    // Up to 100 senders are allowed.
    var senderIds = ["Your-Sender-ID"];
    chrome.gcm.register(senderIds, registerCallback);
  });
});
```

I understand that we have to use `chrome.gcm.register` to register our app, but they haven't mentioned how the token will be obtained. Will the `chrome.gcm.register` method return something which can be used as the registration token? Help me with this please!

P.S: The tutorials that are available are pretty outdated. If anyone has any updated tutorials/samples, do tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback:

```
function registerCallback(registrationId) {
```

will get called and the registrationId passed to it. There you can save it to local storage or do whatever you want.